# Does Jekyll have a scrolling container option?

Tags: html, css, jekyll

I have a Github Pages site and I want to include a scrolling container just like [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-service) (left side, scrolling menu), where any subdirectories and their contents are listed inside the container. Is there a way to accomplish this in Jekyll/HTML/CSS?